# How to run and read bluetoothctl commands outputs from NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, scripting, bluetooth

I want to periodically run commands to `bluetoothctl` via NodeJS, and be able to read the output of those commands.

For example I'd want to run the `scan on`, and get the output. As well as running `devices` and read the list. It's not matter that is a string, I can parse it, but I need to be able to interact with the `bluetoothctl` program.

The problem is that when you type in the terminal the command `bluetoothctl` it brings you in a "manager" like view, where I guess Node cannot read data from? Am I wrong?

I'm kinda lost, and I couldn't find anything useful. I've found some NodeJS bluetoothctl wrappers, but they're all old and requires deprecated versions of node..

#### Edit

Here's the code that I have so far. But the problem is that I don't get the expected output from the commands that I run, but instead I get the name of the command that I've called...

```
import * as cp from 'child_process';

async function sleep(ms) {
    await new Promise(r => setTimeout(() => r(), ms));
    return;
}

function log(m: string) {
    console.log(`[${ShellyBluetoothScanner.name}] ${m}`);
}

export class ShellyBluetoothScanner {

    bluetoothctl: cp.ChildProcessWithoutNullStreams;

    constructor() {
        this.setup();
    }

    async run() {
        log('Running scan and devices list in 2s...');
        await sleep(2000);

        log('Enabling bluetooth');
        this.bluetoothctl.stdin.write('power on');
        await sleep(2000);

        log('Claering devices');
        this.bluetoothctl.stdin.write('remove *');

        log('Scan devices for 3s');
        this.bluetoothctl.stdin.write('scan on');
        await sleep(3000);

        log('Print devices');
        this.bluetoothctl.stdin.write('devices');
    }

    private setup() {
        log('INFO: Setting up bluetooth');
        this.bluetoothctl = cp.spawn('bluetoothctl');
        this.bluetoothctl.stdout.on('data', m => console.log('STDOUT Data - ', m.toString()));
        this.bluetoothctl.stdout.on('error', error => console.log('STDOUT Error - ', error.message));
        log('INFO: Bluetooth setup completed');
    }
}

const SBTS = new ShellyBluetoothScanner();
SBTS.run();
```

Comment: The Archlinux wiki suggests something along the lines of `bluetoothctl -- command`, so that would be `bluetoothctl -- scan on` in your case? (see https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/bluetooth#Console). Alternatively you could probably spawn a separate process for `bluetoothctl` and interact with that using redirect stdin and stdout

Comment: Hey @UnholySheep unfortunately I've already tried that from the terminal, and it brings me into the bluetoothctl console D:

Comment: I'm assuming you mean the first suggestion? Have you also tried spawning a new process using [`child_process.spawn()`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options)?

Comment: I've been trying even with the `spawn` and `exec` methods, both passing the command like `('bluetoothctl -- devices')` and even `('bluetoothctl', ['-- devices'])`. With spawn the first one threw a ENOENT error, while with exec it didn't, the second scenario was just hanging without any errors or messages coming in

Comment: With spawning I don't think you should be providing the command directly, instead write it in via `stdin`, e.g.: `const bluetoothctl = spawn("bluetoothctl"); bluetoothctl.stdin.write("devices");` and read data from `bluetoothctl.stdout`

Comment: @UnholySheep Ohh! You are right! I was passing the commands in the wrong way. But now I've attached the listener on the `stdout.on('data')` but I don't get the output that I expect... I'm updating the question with my code.. could you be so kind and maybe post a small snippet that you get to work on your machine? <3

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe `bluetoothctl` was ever intended to be run in this way. It certainly has no documented API and I have seen the commands subtly change in the tool over time which will break your script.

A better way to achieve this is to use the D-Bus API that is documented and intended for this use.

https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc/adapter-api.txt

https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc/device-api.txt

https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc/gatt-api.txt

There are bindings available at: https://www.npmjs.com/package/dbus

I am sure there are also libraries that maybe helpful. Maybe https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-ble